# Django Redirect URLs to absolute url

Tags: python, django, redirect

I'm new to Django/Python and I'd like to redirect some URLS to another domain.

mydomain.com/blog needs to redirect to 'http://blog.mydomain.com'

How can I go about doing this?

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$',        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/home.html'), name='home'),
        url(r'^blog/$',   TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/blog.html')),
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `RedirectView` generic view

```
url(r'^blog/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='http://blog.mydomain.com')),
```